# Combine many REST results to one

Tags: java, rest

I have REST method receiving `List<String> itemId`

In this method I call SOAP method for each ID from `itemId` list.

I need get for example 10 ID make 10 request to another service and merge data and return this data in my service.

my method receive [1,2,3,4]

```
List<Response> res1 = getItemsFromSOAPService(1)
   List<Response> res2 = getItemsFromSOAPService(2)
   List<Response> res3 = getItemsFromSOAPService(3)
   List<Response> res4 = getItemsFromSOAPService(4)
```

And I need return `res1.getItemsList() + res2.getItemsList() + res3.getItemsList() + res4.getItemsList()`

But getItemsFromSOAPService can return Error. Response:

```
@Data
public class Response {
  private String status;
  private String message;
  private List<Item> itemsList;
}
```

How can I combine data if for example I get `res2`  fith error?

Comment: Throw an exception from getItemsFromSOAPService(), put your 4 calls inside a try{}, handle the error in a catch.

Comment: For a start put get getItemsFromSOAPService() in a loop. Need to see the declaration for getItemsFromSOAPService to understand input params and output. From the class declaration for Response not sure the return will be a list. Java Collection based classes like List have addAll methods.

Comment: Also what is Response.status? Can you use it in an if to check whether or not that call succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Amend getItemsFromSOAPService() to throw an exception when the error is detected. Then use try/catch.

```
try {
    List<Response> res1 = getItemsFromSOAPService(1);
    List<Response> res2 = getItemsFromSOAPService(2);
    List<Response> res3 = getItemsFromSOAPService(3);
    List<Response> res4 = getItemsFromSOAPService(4);

    // do something with the results
} catch ( SoapErrorException theException } {
    // do something with the error
}
```